# Return Promise or boolean depending on parameters with a default

Tags: typescript, boolean

I've got some code which will either return a boolean or a Promise depending on the parameters.

```
function setGuid<B extends boolean>(guid: string, shouldValidate?: B): B extends true ? boolean : Promise<boolean>
function setGuid(guid: string, shouldValidate?: boolean): boolean | Promise<boolean> {
    if (shouldValidate){
        return true
    }
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```

This functionality works. If I call `setGuid("*", false)` it understands that the return type will be a `Promise<boolean>` likewise if I call `setGuid("*", true)` TypeScript understands the return type will be a `boolean`.

The issue is I cannot work out how to set a default return type, that being `Promise<boolean>` if shouldValidate (an optional param) is not provided - I want TypeScript to understand that `setGuid("*")` will return `Promise<boolean>`. Currently if I don't explictly provide `false` as the second parameter it thinks `boolean | Promise<boolean>` is being returned.

The error I'm getting when calling `setGuid("*")` is `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'boolean | Promise<boolean>'. Property 'then' does not exist on type 'false'.`

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't pass anything in as `shouldValidate`, then there is nothing for the compiler to use to infer the type of `B`.  As such, it will tend to default to its constraint, which is `boolean`.  This has poor behavior since `B extends true ? boolean : Promise<boolean>` will become the union `boolean | Promise<boolean>`, as you've seen.

In this case, you could add a [generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to the overload call signature, like this:

```
function setGuid<B extends boolean = false>(
  guid: string, 
  shouldValidate?: B
): B extends true ? boolean : Promise<boolean>;
```

The compiler will use this default if it cannot otherwise infer `B`:

```
setGuid("*").then(x => x ? 0 : 1); // no error now
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.9.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKZQOIhgEwDwBCiqAHlKmDsogEZxwA2qAhkgLyLDMNoB8AFAHNsOAFwooAJxhhBAGhQALOCAY4Aat1zNyAfnEEAlAeJkKVRFJCpEu2vSatE4gAqS4AWxho8dRizBeAChQSFgEFHQsXCERcWQpGXklFTVNBm09cT9HMGN7fycAH0Q3T29UXwcA3kQAbyDEJuaYYER+ZGVVDS0cHVRDesbmkZHJdBBJJCtUYZGAXznm8ahJpDKvNAA6ceRGADdUfhnDAG4gxcQgtEwRfgAiACp7wy2oRQp+EkQ2Wu+7AAMzkQAEYzkA)